# 408 Request Timeout, Apache

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

I cannot upload larger files. The application is Perl based runs on cgi.

**Log 1:** public_html/cgi-bin/logs/upload.log

```
[Thu May 28 14:09:04 2020][5436] [Thu May 28 14:09:04 2020] upload.cgi: CGI.pm: Server closed socket during multipart read (client aborted?).
```

**Log 2:** /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com.error.log

```
[Thu May 28 14:14:09.693395 2020] [cgid:error] [pid 16236:tid 139648529569536] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client IP:50280] AH01270: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://example.com/
```

Getting

> "408 Request Timeout" while uploading more than 3 MB of file!

CentOS 7 using Web Centos Panel

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias http://www.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html
UseCanonicalName Off
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/domain/public_html/cgi-bin/
TimeOut 18000

--------------

<VirtualHost IP:443>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias http://www.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html
UseCanonicalName Off
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/domain/public_html/cgi-bin/
TimeOut 18000
```

Still nothing!

---

If I use `LimitRequestBody 102400` instead of timeout in httpd.conf it shows `Request Entity Too Large` error.

Comment: What are you sending to this CGI program and is it indeed too large?

Comment: I'm running file-sharing website.

Comment: And are those files larger than the limit you set? If you are loading "more than 3MB" (how much more?), then that seems like more than the 102400 byte limit you set.

Comment: I changed the limit to "10000000" which is 10mb and tried uploading 8mb file but got "408 request timeout" at 3.4 MB uploaded file.

Comment: How long did it take to upload that 3.4 MB file? You're asking these questions about time and space and not giving us much to go on.

Comment: It took 3-4 seconds to upload 3.4 MB of the file out of 8 MB.

Answer (score -1):

For me it seems that the upload process is waiting for something. Do you have checked firewall, permissions .... something like that.